# Context free grammar for $A \circ B$

Tags: context-free

If A and B are regular language, what is a context free grammar of the following language?
$$
A \circ B = \{ xy \mid x \in A \text{ and } y \in B \text{ and } |x|=|y| \}
$$

Comment: Hint: Modify a grammar for $\{ a^nb^n : n \geq 0 \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, we can assume that neither $A$ or $B$ contains the empty string. Otherwise, we can either add a simple rule to our final grammar so that it generates the empty string or or do nothing so that our final grammar does not generate the empty string still.

Since $A$ is a regular language that does not contain empty string, we can have $(N_A,\Sigma_A, P_A, S_A)$, a *restricted right-linear* grammar for $A$, where each rule in $P_A$ is of the form $U\to aX$ or $U\to a$, where $U, X\in N_A$ and $a\in\Sigma_A$.

Since $B$ is a regular language that does not contain empty string, we can have $(N_B,\Sigma_B, P_B, S_B)$, a *restricted left-linear* grammar for $B$, where each rule in $P_B$ is of the form $V\to Yb$ or $V\to b$, where $V,Y\in N_B$ and $b\in\Sigma_B$.

Construct the grammar $\left(N_A\times N_B, \Sigma_A\cup\Sigma_B, P, (S_A,S_B)\right)$, where the production rules $P$ is 
$$\{(U,V)\to a(X,Y)b: U\to aX \in P_A\ \land\ V\to Yb \in P_B\}\\
\cup\{(U,V)\to ab: U\to a\in P_A\ \land\ V\to b \in P_B\}.$$

Basically, the grammar rules generate a string by adding a terminal on the left side as in $A$ (I am referring to $U\to aX$) as well as a terminal on the right side as in $B$ (I am referring to $V\to Yb$) at the same time. At the final step, the non-terminal in the middle is replaced by $ab$ (I am referring to $(U,V)\to ab$).

It should not be difficult to verify the constructed grammar is a context-free grammar for $A\circ B$. (In fact, it is a linear grammar.)

Comment: @Mohammad I just simplified this answer. In case "restricted right linear grammar" or "restricted left linear grammar" is not clear, here is [a lecture note](https://www.tau.ac.il/~landman/Online_Class_Notes_file/Formal%20Languages/pdf%202%20Regular%20languages,%20grammars%20and%20automata.pdf). They can be derived from right-linear grammar or left-linear grammar straightforwardly.

Comment: A restricted right linear grammar is essentially a DFA. A restrict left linear grammar is a DFA for the reversed language.

Comment: @Mohammad As Yuval said, a restricted right linear grammar corresponds to a DFA. A non-terminal corresponds to a state in the DFA. The start symbol corresponds to the start state. A production rule corresponds to a transition rule in the DFA.

Comment: Here is a similar exercise that can be solved similarly. Construct a context-free grammar for $A \circ B = \{ xy \mid x \in A \text{ and } y \in B \text{ and } |x|=2|y| \}$, where $A$ and $B$ are two regular languages.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that DFA for $A$ and $B$ are $D_A$ and $D_B$ respectively.
We will construct a PushDown Automata (PDA) for the given language $A \cdot B$ by combining $D_A$ and $D_B$ in a particular manner.

Modify the transitions of $D_A$ such that on reading any letter it pushes a symbol $X$ on the stack. Join all the final states of $D_A$ to the initial state of $D_B$ with epsilon transitions. Modify all the transitions of $D_B$ to Pop $X$ from the stack. **Accepting condition will be that on reading a word we should reach one of the final state of $D_B$ and the stack should be empty.**

It will be quite easy for you to convince yourself that this will accept the language $A \cdot B$ as required. Now, we can apply the standard method to convert the PDA to grammar to get the required grammar.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response, but is there any way I can solve it without using PDA? my teacher hasn't taught about PDA yet, so it should have another way.